# Esto tratando de hacer una consulta sql con una relacion muchos a muchos a traves de una tabla pivote

Tags: php, join, sql, relaciones

estoy tratando de traer los datos de forma que un gestor trabaja en varias  paginas y estoy tratando de mostrar el nombre del gestor y todas las paginas en las que trabaja, con lo cual las tablas para esto están de esta forma:

---

**gestor**

idgestor

gestor

nick

**paginas**

idpaginas

page

moneda

porcentaje

**gestor_has_paginas**

id_gestor_paginas

gestor_idgestor

paginas_idpaginas

---

y estoy tratando de traer los datos de la siguiente forma

|**gestor**  |             **paginas**

|pedro       |             wikiperdia, concarbon, furiuslab |

---

tras mucho investigar conseguí una posible solución y trate de hacerlo de la siguiente manera

> 

```
SELECT idgestor, 
       page, 
       STUFF ((SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ' ,' + L.page
FROM paginas AS L 
INNER JOIN gestor_has_paginas AS WL ON PW.idgestor = WL.idgestor 
AND L.idpaginas = WL.paginas_idpaginas
ORDER BY PW.idgestor, PW.page
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ' ') AS paginas  
FROM PaginasWeb AS PW GROUP BY idgestor, page
```

---

y pues la consulta me da error alguna idea de como podría lograr traer los datos de esa forma?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya que estas usando MYSQL y en esta no existe el STUFF puedes hacer lo siguiente, Usar el GROUP_CONCAT
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php#SP

Comment: hola gracias por responder este es el error que me da 
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' ,' + L.page
                                 FROM paginas AS L 
            ' en la linea 2

Comment: Hola replicando tus tablas noto lo siguiete WL.idgestor que hace referencia a gestor_has_paginas no contiene una definicion de ese dato,fue por error? o me podrias decir si ese es el error?

Comment: no comprendo a que te refieres con que WL.idgestor no contiene una definición del dato

Comment: Veo que pusiste la definición de tus tablas y en la parte donde pones el de la tabla gestor_has_paginas tienes lo siguiente id_gestor_paginas

gestor_idgestor

paginas_idpaginas y en la consulta haces referencia a un campo llamado idgestor y no lo veo no se si ahi sea el error.

Comment: ya te entendí pero el error persiste y modifique el idgestor por WL.gestor_idgestor pero el error persiste 

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' ,' + L.page
                                 FROM paginas AS L 
            ' en la linea 2

Comment: Te pondre en la respuesta algo que estoy haciendo y ayudame a llenar correctamente la tabla, estoy tratando de simular tus tablas para ver donde podria estar el error te dejo lo que estoy usando.

Comment: Pregunta @MiguelDelgado esta consulta la estas usando directo del PHP? si es asi creo que ahi esta el error no logra entenderlo el PHP trata de meterlo en un sp y prueba llamando a ese sp.

Comment: @MiguelDelgado si estas usando MySQL deberías mencionarlo pues me parece la sintaxis de TOP no corresponde

Comment: la consulta la estoy ejecutando directamente en MySQL como aun me genera el error aun no la e llevado al php

Comment: En MYSQL No existe el STUFF, esta es una palabra reservada de SQL para MYSQL podrias checar esto
https://database.guide/whats-the-mysql-equivalent-of-stuff-in-sql-server/

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], realizar aportes que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad

Comment: si hace justamente lo que necesito que haga, voy a probarlo

Comment: perfecto me funciono 
SELECT gestor_idgestor,GROUP_CONCAT(paginas_idpaginas)
FROM gestor_has_paginas
GROUP BY gestor_idgestor 

con esto la consulta me trae justo lo que necesito muchas gracias

Comment: De nada
Saludos